# Commented block indentation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, format, comments

Is there a way to avoid "expected indent block" errors in Python without adding pass to a function?

```
def exclamation(s):
 # s += "!!!"
 # return s

print exclamation("The indented horror")
```

The above code results in an error on line 5. Yes, remove the comments and the code works fine. However, in debugging stuff I often find myself in a similar situation. Is this just a hang-up of the off-side rule and something I need to get used to or are there ways around this?

Comment: Note that the "something" can be a docstring, so if you *"comment out the body"* with `"""` then the function will compile.

Answer (score 3):

There has to be something within your function definition to avoid a `SyntaxError`.

The issue is that the interpreter will [effectively ignore comments during parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments), and so while to a *human* it might look like something is there, to the *parser* it is empty.

As jonrsharpe has pointed out in a comment, you can use docstrings to "comment out" your code and have it still work. This is because the docstring is, in effect, a normal string. As such this will be parsed and won't cause a `SyntaxError`. To take your example code it would look like:

```
def exclamation(s):
  '''s += "!!!"
  return s'''

# This should print None as nothing is now returned from the func
print(exclamation("The indented horror"))
```